# Don't want RAID to autostart

Tags: kernel, raid, system, initramfs

I have software RAID in my system, and I would REALLY like it NOT to automatically start at system boot.

Ubuntu system is installed on a partition not on a RAID (no need whatsoever to start raid for booting system)

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS
Release:        12.04
Codename:       precise

uname -a
Linux coruscant 3.2.0-29-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 27 17:03:23 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I did try to:

- Manually prevent anything (module/script) MD/RAID to be loaded in initramfs image
- Blacklist raid module
- Passing to the kernel `raid=noautodetect`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

When booting to ubuntu live CD, you will see a picture of a man and a keyboard. Press any key to get in the menu. You will see a menu named "other options" and then you will see an entry for the raid. Good luck!